# Console Application input parameters - string identification

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, console-application

I have a console app that takes in string parameters. The app runs through the command line like so:

> C:\ExampleApp.exe this is a "test"

In the above example, there are 4 different strings read in as parameters.. Is there any way to determine which parameter had quotes around it?  When I do a `Console.WriteLine(args[3])`, it prints out as test and not "test".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Environment.CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.environment.commandline%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
returns a complete command line as a single string, just parse it and you will get the original parameters, quoted or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the quotes are stripped by the framework before beeing passed to your main function, have you tried to escape the qoutes using a backslash?